# Can my React Native app run in the background to listen to message from a Bluetooth device to wake the app up?

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin

I am building a beacon device, which can send data through Bluetooth to a connected device(my phone). To respond to the received data, I'm writing a React Native app. Once connected I want my app to keep running in background listening if some data is received from the connected Bluetooth beacon and then maybe do something with it like push notification or start the app up and sound the alarm.

Answer (score 0):

for do this, you should run your tasks for send and get data while your app not open on mobile, and you can use some packages such as '**react-native-background-fetch**' for run your task in background.
I hope could helped to you